# How can I configure external applications used for downloads in Chromium?

Tags: banshee, chromium, downloads

I subscribe to emusic and would like to be able to browse and download songs using Chromium.

Their downloads are implemented using a special XML file with an .emx extension that can be opened using banshee. I cannot find a way to configure Chromium to open these downloads with banshee. It does detect the content type (application/vnd-emusic-emusic_list). Is there any way to configure the external applications Chromium uses for downloads with a particular extension or content type?

(I know that I can use banshee emusic extension to browse but I would like to be able to use a standard web browser as well. In Firefox I can do this easily in the applications tab  in preferences.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium uses `xdg-mine` to determine what program will be responsible for opening a file.

Download one of the .emx files and type this on the terminal:

```
xdg-mime query filetype <filedownloaded>.emx
```

You should get this sort of output

```
<file type>; charset=<charset>
```

To determine the current program set to open this file type, run:

```
xdg-mime query default <file type>
```

To set a default application for it (in your case `banshee`), run:

```
xdg-mime default banshee.desktop <filetype>
```

This will make chromium open the .emx files with the program specified with `xdg-mime`.